# How to setup Rx.Observable.fromEvent to work with jQuery filtered events

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs

There are lots of examples of `Rx.Observable.fromEvent(element, eventName)` using a jquery selection as the element to capture events from. However is it possible for Rx listen to only events from a filtered event setup with jQuery?

```
//Bind the event on body but only respond to events that match the filter
$('body').on('click', '.aClass div .something', function () {...});

//Bind to 'body' but only respond to events from the binding above
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(/*something here?*/);
```

I have come up with something effectively similar but it seems like it would be much more costly than the jquery filter.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('body'), 'click')
.filter(function (e) {
  return $(e.target).is('.aClass div .something');
})
.subscribe(function () {...});
```

Is there some way I could turn the jQuery binding into an emitter and use that event stream with Rx? 
What's the best approach?

Comment: see if this helps - http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/bridging_to_events.html#bridging-to-custom-events-with-fromeventpattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/ktzk1bh3/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="aClass">
    <div>
        <a class="something">Click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Bind to 'body' but only respond to events from the binding above
var source = Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {
    $('body').on('click', '.aClass div .something', function(ev) {
        o.onNext(ev);
    })
});

var sub = source.subscribe(function(ev) { console.log("click", ev) });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromeventpattern.md).

```
Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
  function add(handler) {
    $('body').on('click', '.aClass div .something', handler);
  },
  function remove(handler) {
    $('body').off('click', '.aClass div .something', handler);
  }
);
```

This way it will automatically remove event handler on unsubscribe from observable subscription.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='radios'>
  <input type='radio' name='r' value='PM'>PM
  <input type='radio' name='r' value='PCE'>PCE
  <input type='radio' name='r' value='PCS'>PCS
</div>
<textarea class='textarea'>

</textarea>
```

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('.radios'),'click')
.subscribe((e)=>console.log(e.target.value));
```